# How to remove all items from combo box GTK C code?

Tags: c, gtk

I have followed code that fills my combo box with items: `aaaa`, `bbbb`, .... :

```
GtkWidget *combo_screen_share;
GtkListStore *store;
GtkTreeIter iter;

       combo_screen_share=app_gtk_get_widget(/* .... */);


        GtkTreeModel *model;

        GtkCellRenderer *renderer=gtk_cell_renderer_text_new();

        model=GTK_TREE_MODEL((store=gtk_list_store_new(1,G_TYPE_STRING)));
        gtk_combo_box_set_model(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo_screen_share),model);
        gtk_cell_layout_pack_start(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo_screen_share),renderer,TRUE);
        gtk_cell_layout_set_attributes(GTK_CELL_LAYOUT(combo_screen_share),renderer,"text",0,NULL);


        gtk_list_store_append(store,&iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(store,&iter,0,_("aaaa"),-1);

        gtk_list_store_append(store,&iter);
        gtk_list_store_set(store,&iter,0,_("bbbb"),-1);

        // and so on....
```

How can I invoke "clearAll" to remove all items from combo,

I thought to recreate  `model` with `gtk_list_store_new`

but get instead:

```
aaaa      aaaa
bbbb      bbbb
```

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the same code you placed above you just need to call

```
    gtk_list_store_clear (store);
```

You might want to check the ownership of those string since I'm not pretty wure how it goes. Yet, the documentation is pretty good on those: [GtkListStore](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkListStore.html)

Answer (score 1):

first off it's really strange that I didn't find any document how to remove all items from combo box for GTK+ C code.

From my experience with Swing I went straight and set `NULL` for `model`:

```
 gtk_combo_box_set_model(GTK_COMBO_BOX(combo_screen_share),NULL);
```

and it worked for me.

I don't know if its good way, still waits for other responses.

Comment: This one works, and it's designed like this. I mean passing NULL to this method unset the model in the combo.
Now, the other approach will be clearing the model with: *gtk_list_store_clear*.

Comment: if it works for you, I will be glad to give you up vote on `gtk_list_store_clear`. Just give simple example, please

Comment: @erick2red, strange that I didn't find similar question, sounds like I ask it 1st time ;)